# ROS built-in primitive types not declared

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am new in using ROS. I see a problem with ROS built-in primitive type, such as int16.

Here is the code, it is very simple.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
 
int main(int argc, char** argv)                                                                   
{                                                                                                 
  int16 i = 0;
  ros::init(argc, argv, "data_broadcaster");                                                      
  ros::NodeHandle n;
 
  ros::Rate loop_rate(100);
 
  while(ros::ok())                                                                                
  {
    loop_rate.sleep();
    i = i + 4;
    if (i == 360) i = 0;                                                                          
  }                                                                                               
  return 0;                                                                                       
}
```

I run `catkin_make` to build the code and get the following error.

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object data_capturer/CMakeFiles/data_broadcaster.dir/src/data_broadcaster.cpp.o
/home/kening/catkin_ws_2/src/data_capturer/src/data_broadcaster.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/kening/catkin_ws_2/src/data_capturer/src/data_broadcaster.cpp:5:3: error: ‘int16’ was not declared in this scope
   int16 i = 0;
   ^
/home/kening/catkin_ws_2/src/data_capturer/src/data_broadcaster.cpp:17:5: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
     i = i + 4;
     ^
data_capturer/CMakeFiles/data_broadcaster.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'data_capturer/CMakeFiles/data_broadcaster.dir/src/data_broadcaster.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [data_capturer/CMakeFiles/data_broadcaster.dir/src/data_broadcaster.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:837: recipe for target 'data_capturer/CMakeFiles/data_broadcaster.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [data_capturer/CMakeFiles/data_broadcaster.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(data_capturer)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)
catkin_package()
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(data_broadcaster src/data_broadcaster.cpp)
add_dependencies(data_broadcaster
  ${data_broadcaster_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
  ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)
target_link_libraries(data_broadcaster
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

My `package.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>data_capturer</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The data_capturer package</description>
  <maintainer email="myemail@whereisit.com">Ku</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>

  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

I could not figure out why `int16` is not declared. Did I forget to include any header file. Or is there something wrong with my `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`?

Please help.
Thank you.
-Kening

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255572/ros-built-in-primitive-types-not-declared/) by [Kening Ren](https://answers.ros.org/users/29479/kening-ren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I see a problem with ROS built-in primitive type, such as `int16`.

The only place where `int16` is a legal identifier in a ROS context (ignoring custom type definitions in the various languages that have client libraries) is in the ROS [msg specification](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Message_Description_Specification). You cannot use those directly in any client code, as they are mapped onto types native to the language in which the client library is written.

For C++, `int16` is mapped onto `int16_t`. `int16` is not a type in C++, so the compiler error is to be expected.

> Did I forget to include any header file

Add `#include <cstdint>` to your `.cpp` file and try again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0